# MongoDB find an object in DB and update its field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

## Problem

I have a NodeJS app connecting to a MongoDB. I am tracking how many times something occurred. So, what I want is:

1. Check if my constructed object is in the database (excluding field with number of occurrences)
2. If so, update its occurrences +=1
3. If not, set occurrences = 1 and insert it

I have a working code:

```
  const isInDb = await collection.findOne({
     // match all other fields except for the occurrences field
  });
  if(!isInDb) {
    parsedElement.occurrences = 1;
    await collection.insertOne(parsedElement);
  } else {
    await collection.updateOne(isInDb, { $inc: { "occurrences": 1 } });
  }
```

## My question

Isn't there a better way? Ideally, it'd be something like collection.findAndUpdate or with upsert or something similar. What I wrote is functional, but seems inefficient to me, since I first have to query the DB for a look-up, and then query it for update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updateOne takes a third parameter for options. Set upsert: true.

```
collection.updateOne({ /* match properties */ }, { $inc: { "occurrences": 1 } }, { upsert: true })
```

Comment: Scratch my previous comment, I had an error elsewhere. Worked... Thank you :))

Answer (score 1):

```
collection.updateOne({ /* match properties */ }, {
  $set: parsedElement,
  $inc: {
    "occurrences": 1
  }
}, {
  upsert: true
})
```

Comment: Also worked, thank you... Had an error elsewhere, my apologies.